# React Native testing android and ios component

Tags: react-native, react-native-testing-library

I have a code that goes like this:

```
function AppContainerAndroid() {
  return <App />;
}

function AppContainerIOS() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider testID="ios_area_provider">
      <App />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

function RenderProperContainer({renderProps}) {
  return renderProps();
}

export default function AppContainer() {
  return (
    <RenderProperContainer
      renderProps={() => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          return <AppContainerAndroid />;
        }

        return <AppContainerIOS />;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

and a test that looks like this.

```
it('should render android platform', () => {
    setPlatform('android');
    const {getByTestId} = render(<AppContainer />);

    const element = getByTestId('ios_area_provider');

    console.log(element);
});
```

When I run the test I get an error saying

[image]

Did some searching and most of the answers I get says it has something to do with the way I return the component. It appears that it does not allow conditional return because I already tried:

```
export default function AppContainer() {
     if(Platform.OS === 'android') {
         return <AppContainerAndroid />
     }

     return <AppContainerIOS />
}
```

and

```
export default function AppContainer() {
  return Platform.OS === 'android' ? (
    <AppContainerAndroid />
  ) : (
    <AppContainerIOS />
  );
}
```

and get the same error. Is there a way to handle this kind of scenario?

**UPDATE**: This is what's inside my `<App />` for some reason somewhere in my react navigation is causing the issue because `<WrapWithProvider><View /></WrapWithProvider>` works just fine, the test passed.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <WrapWithProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen>
            {() => <View />}
          </Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </WrapWithProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try use if ios instead.

Something like:

```js
return Platform.OS === 'ios' ? <AppContainerIOS /> : <App />;
```

**Update**

Try this without [`SafeAreaView`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview):

> The purpose of SafeAreaView is to render content within the safe area boundaries of a device. It is currently only applicable to iOS devices with iOS version 11 or later.

And `Stack.Screen` didn't set component.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <WrapWithProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="landing_page" options={{headerShown: false}} component={landing_page}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </WrapWithProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I applied your code but the same result... the test pass if I only return one component like `return <AppContainerAndroid />`;

Comment: Maybe just return like this  `return <App/>` because it looks do nothing  in `AppContainerAndroid`?

Comment: I separated them because of the iOS SafeAreaProvider, I just want to test if android return the <App /> if ios wrap the <App /> inside <SafeAreaProvider />

Comment: yep, I know, I means maybe you could try like answer updated. If it still have error code.

Comment: Also this error happens when using `react-test-renderer` or `react-native-testing-library`

Comment: Thanks you so much, I think the error is inside the <App /> it is not really the conditional return... :)

Comment: Maybe you could post the <App /> component to let more possible to find out problem.

Comment: I have update my post I included the content inside my <App />

Comment: The purpose of SafeAreaView is to render content within the safe area boundaries of a device. It is currently only applicable to iOS devices with iOS version 11 or later. [DOC](https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview)  But you put in <App/> use in android? So that cause this error?

Comment: I remove the SafeAreaView now and updated my post, still my test fails.

Comment: I know the problem! It because the stack.screen using without component, try new update

Comment: So that there is no any render, fit the error code's end description. return null or render nothing. Take it a try

Comment: Did some thinking and tried mocking the NavigationContainer `jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => ({
      NavigationContainer: jest.fn().mockImplementation((f) => []),
    }));` and it worked... :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is I have to mock the `NavigationContainer`.

```
jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => ({
  NavigationContainer: jest.fn().mockImplementation((f) => []),
}));
```

The test successfully passed now.

Comment: where do you call this from?  I'm trying to mock the Platform.OS in individual tests